# efficient way to find if a list of words is in string?

Tags: python, nltk

I have a python list with 2000 called *words_list* elements and a list of 1000 long strings called "paragraphs_list"... I want to know what is the most efficient way to know if the elements of *words_list* are substring of the elements of "paragraphs_list" (*case insensitive*)?

I tried with:

```
for word in words_list:
    for paragraph in paragraphs_list:
        if word in paragraph:
            print "success"
```

But I think that maybe there is a better way to compare the two lists. I tried using [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) and the concordance function but, I can't read my paragraphs_list without generating a file, but is not neccesary becouse I dont' need to read a file, only a plain text. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the words to match complete elements of `paragraphs_list`, or to be substrings? The answer you accepted doesn't do what you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set`, it's like a hash table, so detecting if a string is in the set is O(1).

```
paragraphs_set = set(paragraphs_list)
for word in words_list:
    if word in paragraphs_set:
        print "success"
```

Comment: Use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). Not `Set` from the `sets` module. In Python 2.6 or newer.